# Automatic report generation in sql management studio

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I was wondering if there is any option to generate reports in sql management studio automatically in pdf format. I know it is possible to do it manually by left-clicking in the report and then Export -> Pdf what what  need is to set a time that the report is generated in pdf format and stored somewhere automatically.

Comment: Of use? http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13266/how-do-i-automatically-deliver-the-sql-server-built-in-reports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into Subscriptions?

[Microsoft website: Subscriptions and Delivery (Reporting Services)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159762(v=sql.110).aspx)